# Based on previous records, stop sum fields

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-14

I have a table like this:

```
|id |   date     | point |
+---+------------+-------+
| 6 | 2022/01/06 |   9   |
| 5 | 2022/01/05 |   7   |
| 4 | 2022/01/04 |   1   |
| 3 | 2022/01/03 |   4   |
| 2 | 2022/01/02 |   6   |
| 1 | 2022/01/01 |   1   |
```

My goal is to obtain `sum` of `point`s from date now to date that the point is greater than equal to 1 and stop sum of fields before that date.

In the example above (order by date), the answer is `sum` of points date now(`2022/01/06`) to the date `2022/01/04` and equals `9 + 7 + 1 = 17`. Because the point value for date `2022/01/03` is equal to 4, therefore is not calculated in `sum`.

I read about [CTE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL#Common_table_expression) and [Window Functoin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function_(SQL)) however, I wasn't able to implement them properly.

Comment: What database and version are you using?

Comment: @Schwern Postgres database and latest version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Find the first row before (and including) the desired date whose point value is 1.
2. Sum up that and everything newer than it up to (and including) the desired date.

```
select sum(point)
from points
where date between (
  select "date"
  from points
  where point = 1 and date <= '2022/01/06'
  order by "date" desc
  limit 1
) and '2022/01/06';
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=27b8866c4ee8eb492a5b06effdab635c)